# Patch-Based Image Processing alternating direction methods of multipliers (ADMM)

Tags: lagrange-multiplier, image-processing, block-matrices

Hi everyone I meet a problem recently, which is about image processing. The application is image reconstruction.

Originally I want to use ADMM to solve the pixel-based problem which involves gradient and Laplacian matrix. But I find that patch-based image processing is more suitable for image reconstruction.

Therefore, I want to modify the original problem into patch-based one. That is, I divide the original problem into several patches. And then implement ADMM for each patch in parallel. Finally convert the resulting blocks into a big picture.

But I dont know whether this is practicable. Is parallel ADMM for each patch better than pixel-based ADMM? Could anyone provide some suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I presented a method a little like this in section 5.4 (p. 98) of my dissertation here: https://escholarship.org/uc/item/4z1126w3

Comment: @littleO Thanks for your help. I read it now

Comment: It's not exactly like what you mentioned, but it's related. By the way, if you haven't already read Boyd's ADMM monograph, it's really useful.